# How do I code a 'confirm send' button on my VisualForce page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, commandbutton, apex-param

I have the following commandButton which runs the javascript function 'sendEmails'. This runs an ApexFunction which runs apex code to create and send an email from the controller. I need to add in a 'Confirm you want to send this email' modal dialog though to prevent accidental sending of emails. So the function should only be executed if the confirmation box *OK* is clicked. How do I do this please?

```
<apex:commandButton value="Send" rendered="{!showEmail}" 
     onClick="sendEmails();return false;"
     styleClass="slds-button slds-button_neutral" />
```

If I replace the 'onClick' event with:

```
onClick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to send the email?'));return false;"
```

then how do I get it to run the 'sendEmail()' function?

My javascript with the actionFunction it calls is:

```
function sendEmails(){                
   var temp = document.getElementsByClassName('emailbody')[0].id;
   var ckeditorBody = CKEDITOR.instances[temp].getData();
   CallSendEmail(ckeditorBody);
}

<apex:actionFunction name="CallSendEmail" action="{!sendEmail}" rerender="errorMessageId">
    <apex:param name="Richbody" value="" assignTo="{!body}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two way

1. Add your method to action and add onclick method

   onClick="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to send the email?')){return true;}else{return false;}"
2. You can call action function

   onClick="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to send the email?')){CallSendEmail();}"